# SVG Chrome Rendering Bug with Dominant Baseling inside Group Transform

Tags: svg

The second X in the circle below is aligned vertical centrally on Firefox but not on Chrome, is this a bug?

The first X is aligned correctly on both.

```html
<svg height="200">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="red"></circle>
  <text x="100" y="100" dominant-baseline="central"  text-anchor="middle" font-size="50">X</text>
</svg>
<svg width="340px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 29.41"><g transform="translate(8.333333333333334 7.500000000000001) scale(15.000000000000002 15.000000000000002)"><circle cx="0" cy="0" r="0.5" fill="red"></circle><text x="0" y="0" dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" font-size="0.4">X</text></g></svg>
```

Comment: I suppose it has to do with the fact that the font-size is very small. You may try to change both circle's radius and font size to something bigger instead of scaling

Comment: Thanks enxaneta. I've been experimenting since and yes I found this is the case. I assumed the transform would take care of it, but there must be a bug in chrome where despite the transform it treats it like a tiny font (which it isn't really!)

Comment: Yes. This is a known bug in Chrome. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=626936